# laravel create symlink in custom public path

Tags: laravel

I have deployed my laravel application on shared hosting. I have  moved all my filed and folders from `public` directory to `public_html`.

This is my directory structure

```
my-laravel-folder
public_html
  index.php
```

Now i am trying to create `symlink` in `public_html` using command `php artisan storage:link`. but this command create `symlink` in `public` directory.

what should i do to create symlink in `public_html` using command `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: Do it manually. The `storage:link` command is simply a wrapper for generating a symlink on your system, but you can do it manually, generally with a `ln -s` command (or similar, depending on your OS)

Comment: You can create with command, **ln -s target_path link_path**  Ex : `ln -s /home/username/my-laravel-folder/storage/app/public /home/username/public_html`

Comment: You should not do that, unless it' the only way. Just change the root directory of the hosting to your public directory, instead of moving public dir. contents out. That can be done from inside .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps to create a symlink

First go to root directory of file system by running this command

```
cd /
```

Then run this command

```
ln -s /path-to/my-laravel-folder/storage/app/public /path-to/public_html/storage
```

I faced the same problem on Hostinger and I was able to fix this by running the following command in the root directory.

```
ln -s /home/MY_USERNAME/domains/MY-DOMAIN.COM/my-laravel-folder/storage/app/public /home/MY_USERNAME/domains/MY-DOMAIN.COM/public_html/storage
```